# Ransack sort link for has many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, has-many, ransack

Rails 4.2.4, Ruby 2.2.3, Ransack 1.7.0

I have a model as:

```
class Patient < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :patient_statuses

   def latest_status
     self.patient_statuses.last.status
   end
end
```

Another model as:

```
class PatientStatus < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :patient

  enum status: [:registered, :pending, :check_up, :admitted, :discharged]
end
```

I have `PatientsController#index` action as

```
def index
    @query = Patient.ransack(params[:q])
    @patients = @query.result
end
```

How can i sort patients by `latest_status`?

As like

```
sort_link @query, :package_latest_status, 'Status' # index.html.erb
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it works but have you tried ?

```
Model.status.find_each
```

e.g.

```
Patient.registered.find_each
Patient.pending.find_each
```